# Check in not trigger all applications in Jenkins to rebuild, only one

Tags: jenkins

My understanding of Jenkins is that, if you have a repo (say a Git repo) that is tied to a Jenkins build, a check-in will trigger a complete repo re-build.  But if you have a number of applications as part of your repo, is there a way to limit which applications will rebuild in response to a check-in?  If you make a change to one application, is there a way to set up your Jenkins build process to that that check-in triggers a rebuild of that application alone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but your understanding is wrong... Jenkins and Git talk to each other using hooks and if these hooks are connected to your build, only then will they build the application/branch in your repo... So unless you have specified that everything must be built, then all the application will be built, otherwise the one you checked in ...will trigger only that build

If you want, you can create a new job and add the GIT SCM hook(during configuration) and do a check in, it will build only your project and any other project that **is using the same hook**- key point to note here :)

So if all your applications are building then you have a configuration issue

Hope this helps :)